# SEIR infection charts going up and down

Tags: anylogic, systemdynamics

I have a problem constructing my SEIR model for system dynamics.

I want to create an infectious character chart that goes up, down and up again.

How do I go about creating it, the current one that I simulated goes up the down meaning that the virus comes to an end at some point.

Comment: SEIR means that there's no reinfection after recovery, so yes the virus comes to an end

Comment: Hi, this place works best for you if you ask very specific questions, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is too broad and open-ended, SOF does not work this way. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focussed on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow Treat us as very busy colleagues that are happy to help. The more effort you put into your question, the more likely you will get a reply :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your infections to go up and down you need to have a transition where a person is either not immune or their immunity ends, see the stock and flow diagram below.

[image]

This is then technically a SIRS model as the person becomes Recovered and can become susceptible again.

I used a model from the AnyLogic Cloud as a base
https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/d465d1f5-f1fc-464f-857a-d5517edc2355?mode=SETTINGS

Comment: Just note that this (great) answer is focussed on Agent-based modelling, original question was on SD, I believe.

Comment: Oops, Thank you @Benjamin I updared my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. I now see the light. -Banele

Comment: Thank you @BaneleMbendane, if you found my answer useful, please remember to accept it, and upvote if you think it is a good answer ;-)